# I am trying to subquery with Left outer join and its giving me error. can some one take a look? Please

Tags: sql, oracle, join

In this query other than 5 join tables i am trying to use 6th table "Days"  to compare value with three tables in joins. but it give me error that i cant use subquery in joins.

```
select
a.ID, a.Name, a.AMT, b.Address, c.Date, c.Pay, d.Check
from
Table1 a 
left outer join Table2 b        on a.ID = b.ID
left outer join Table3 c    on a.ID = c.ID and c.Date= (select Derived_date from  Days where TODAY_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
left outer join Table4 d    on a.ID = d.ID and d.Date= (select Derived_date from Days where TODAY_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
left outer join Table5 e    on a.ID = e.ID and e.Date= (select Derived_date from Days where TODAY_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
```

Comment: Days table has two columns (TODAY_DATE, DERIVED_DATE)

Comment: I checked Parenthesis are ok, i am getting this message. "ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"

Comment: Can anyone suggest me any solution or any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to use a subselect in an `ON` clause isn't going to work to well. You'd need to `JOIN` back to it like you would any other table. Since your subselect is the same for every single `JOIN`, I'd put that in a (temp?) table first so you can `JOIN` to it normally and not have to `SELECT` the same data three times.

```
CREATE TABLE Derived_Dates AS SELECT Derived_date FROM Days WHERE TODAY_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')

SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.AMT, b.Address, c.Date, c.Pay, d.Check
FROM Table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 c ON a.ID = c.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 d ON a.ID = d.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 e ON a.ID = e.ID
    INNER JOIN Dervied_date dt ON c.Date = dt.Derived_date
        AND d.Date = dt.Derived_date
        AND e.Date = dt.Derived_date
```

Here's how you can do it with your subselect:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.AMT, b.Address, c.Date, c.Pay, d.Check
FROM Table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 c ON a.ID = c.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 d ON a.ID = d.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 e ON a.ID = e.ID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Derived_date FROM Days WHERE TODAY_DATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')) dt ON c.Date = dt.Derived_date
        AND d.Date = dt.Derived_date
        AND e.Date = dt.Derived_date
```

Instead of `JOIN`ing back to your derived dates, you could also just use a `WHERE` clause. You have some options, and you might want to make some changes for your particular implementation, but this is more or less how I'd approach this.

Comment: @Qasim0787: No problem. If the solution is working for you, you should mark the answer as accepted.